# Homework-lile questions about Poincare transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

Here is a page from a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6266) which I am currently reading. This page mainly talk about Poincare symmetry.

[image]

Now I can not understand how is Eq.（3.32） is derived. Also Eq.(3.28) looks odd to me. Why there are $\chi$ and $\chi'$ there? And is $\varepsilon_{ij}=\eta_{ik}\varepsilon^k_{\ \ j}$?
I am sorry if I have asked some naive questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I give a answer to my question.

First, for the $\chi$ in (3.28), I think it's a typo (if somebody have a different understanding, please tell me).

Second, according to Eq.(3.27) and (3.28), we have
$$(\delta^i_{\ \ j}+\varepsilon^i_{\ \ j})(\delta^j_{\ \ k}+\varepsilon^j_{\ \ k})=\delta^i_{\ \ k}$$
hence $\varepsilon^i_{\ \ j}+\varepsilon^j_{\ \ i}=0$. Generally, we have the condition $g_{ij}a^i_{\ \ k}a^j_{\ \ l}=g_{kl}$. Then we have $\varepsilon_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ij}=0$, where $\varepsilon_{ij}=g_{ik}\varepsilon^k_{\ \ j}$.

Third, let's derive Eq.(3.32). 
$$(\partial_k\chi)'=\frac{\partial(\chi'(x'))}{\partial x'^k}=\frac{\partial(\chi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ij}S_{ij}\chi(x))}{\partial(x^k+\varepsilon^k_{\ \ l}x^l+\varepsilon^k)}=\frac{\partial(\chi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ij}S_{ij}\chi(x))}{(\delta^k_{\ \ l}+\varepsilon^k_{\ \ l})\partial x^l}\\=(\delta^l_{\ \ k}-\varepsilon^l_{\ \ k})\frac{\partial(\chi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ij}S_{ij}\chi(x))}{\partial x^l}.$$

Then Eq.(3.32) is obtained.